# i'm designing flutter web, i have a problem when minimizing manual appears right overflowed, i've written fit bok but still no effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

this my code

i'm designing flutter web, i have a problem when minimizing manual appears right overflowed, i've written fit bok but still no effect

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web/fonts.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Stack( //Using a Stack you can position widgets over one another.
              children: [
                Image.asset('assets/Landing Page.png',
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, //agar menyesuaikan sesuai widget
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 100),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
```

Comment: What is your problem? What should it look like, what does it look like right now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am confused, i'am designing flutter for the web but if I minimize my chrome, my web is overflowing, how to fix it?